# Old bundle version being served up (cached) after copy to server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundler

I have the following code which works fine on my local machine. Changes + build results in a new bundled file including the modified js code. However, when copied to our staging environment, an old version is being served up, so js changes are not seen.

Files copied include new dlls after a full rebuild + the changed js file. I've also recycled the web (even rebooted).

Even when I turn off optimisation, the staging site is still rendering the optimised script tag rather than a list of js files. Going off my head here.

Any ideas?

```
private void RegisterBundles()
    {
        BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/opt/code-scripts").Include(
            "~/Scripts/ga.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
            "~/Scripts/code.js",
            "~/Scripts/twitterFetcher.js",
            "~/Scripts/tcode.js",
            "~/Scripts/waypoints.js",
            "~/Scripts/waypoints-sticky.js",
            "~/Scripts/code-twitter.js"
            ));
        BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/opt/code-styles").Include(
            "~/css/fonts.css",
            "~/css/site.css"
            ));
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
    }
```

...

```
@Scripts.Render("~/opt/code-scripts")
```